# call sql function in stored procedure with different userId each time

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a sql function and using sql server 2005.

> dbo.util (@dailyDate,@userId)

Now I want to call this function for each @userId for a particular Date.So I am writing a Stored Procedure.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[DailyAttendenceTemp]
 @dailyDate nvarchar(10)
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
Select * FROM dbo.util (@dailyDate,@userId) //I think error is here.
WHERE @userId in (SELECT UserId From TTransactionLog1)
GO
```

but when I execute the procedure it give the error that-

> SQL Server Database Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@userId".

So please tell me how to correct the procedure so that I give only date as a parameter and it run for the same function for each @userId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,,now I am using While loop and it solve my problem.......

```
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @userid nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @numrows int

DECLARE @tempUserId_table TABLE (
    idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1)
    , userid nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT @tempUserId_table
SELECT distinct UserID FROM TUser 


-- enumerate the table
SET @i = 1
SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tempUserId_table)
IF @numrows > 0
    WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @tempUserId_table))
    BEGIN


        -- get the next userId primary key
        SET @userid = (SELECT userid FROM @tempUserId_table WHERE idx = @i)



          Select * FROM dbo.util (@dailyDate,@userid) 


        -- increment counter for next userId
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```